# In Unix, how do I display the contents of all files that begin with a prefix?

Tags: unix, command-line

a bunch of text files that start with the prefix `r_` , and I want to display the contents of all these files at once.

I tried to use `cat` and a command like this :

```
cat [f_*]  ,
```

But this doesn't work  like I expect

Answer (score 1):

Using that `cat` properly:

```
$ cat r_*
```

As there is some mixup in the OP about the starting letter, go ahead and use this: `cat [fr]_*` .

Answer (score 1):

you can use tail or head commands,

```
 tail -n +1 r_*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script something like this

```
path="<Your Path Here>"

find $path -name "r_*" | while read -r currentFile;
do
    while read -r line;
    do
            HERE $line will be each line 
    done < $currentFile
done
```

Here `find $path -name "r_*"` will find all the files starting with a r_ in the given path and iterate each file one by one.
The loop `while read -r line` will read each line content for you to perform any action